# how can I freeze cameraX preview in Android?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I want the camera to freeze preview when the image capture button is pressed. I have looked at other stack-overflow questions but they they are outdated.

cameraX version I am using: 1.0.0-beta03

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a "proper" way to do it yet, but a couple of ways to achieve it include:

- Stop the preview stream by unbinding the `Preview` use case, take the picture, then bind a **new** `Preview` use case to continue the preview stream.
  For this approach to work, you'd need to also have an `ImageAnalysis` use case bound, since `ImageCapture` cannot take a picture if it's the only bound use case (another `Preview` or `ImageAnalysis` use case has to also be bound, check out the official documentation on [the possible use case combinations](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#combine-use-cases)). While this approach works, it would result in a slight delay between the moment the `ImageCapture` callback is called, and when the preview continues, during this time the screen will be blank.
- At the moment you take a picture, use the latest frame from `ImageAnalysis` to display it on top of the preview, you can convert the frame -which is an `ImageProxy`- to a `Bitmap` and display it in an `ImageView`. Once the `ImageCapture` callback is invoked, remove the frame and continue the preview.

Edit:

Starting from camera-view version 1.0.0-alpha12, you can get a `Bitmap` representation of the preview using [`PreviewView.getBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView#getBitmap()). Using this method, you can get the `Bitmap` representation of the preview at the moment the user takes a picture, show it on top of the preview in an `ImageView`, then once an image capture result is available, hide the image.

Comment: How to make preview view blank ? How to remove the frame ?

Answer (score 0):

Also I think you can try and create (as a workaround) a custom LifecycleOwner wrapper and manually set lifecycle state to ON_PAUSE when you want to pause preview. So it will be something like this:

```
class CameraXLifecycleOwner : LifecycleOwner {

    private val lifecycle = LifecycleRegistry(this)

    private val observer = object : LifecycleObserver {
        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
        fun onCreate() {
            lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
        fun onResume() {
            lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
        fun onStart() {
            lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
        fun onPause() {
            lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
        fun onStop() {
            lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
        fun onDestroy() {
            lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
        }
}

fun attachLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {
    lifecycle.currentState = lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
}

fun detachLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
}

fun pauseCamera() {
    lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
}

fun resumeCamera() {
    lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
}

override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle = lifecycle
```

}

So you then wrap default fragment's viewLifecycleOwner by passing it to attachLifecycleOwner() and this way the wrapper will repeat all viewLifecycleOwner's states, but then you can also call pauseCamera()/resumeCamera() to manually change state faking onPause/onResume state change. Not sure it's the best idea, but it's an idea.